# Using Android AsyncTask to download html file

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i just started with android and i'm working on a simple app that should download contents of a html file. I'm using AsyncTask as suggested, but i'm encountering one problem. In the following code (i followed a tutorial code), i get `tv cannot be resolved` for the `onPostExecute` method. How to access the downloaded file? Thank You:

```
public class FlashResults extends Activity {
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(tv);
        readWebpage(tv);                
  }


  protected class DownloadPage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
          protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

          String responseStr = null;

          try {
              for (String url : urls) {   
              DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
              HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);
              HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
              responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
              } 
          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

          } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

          } catch (IOException e) {

          }
          return responseStr;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
          tv.setText(result);
      }
  }

  public void readWebpage(View v) {
        DownloadPage task = new DownloadPage();
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://seznam.cz" });
      }
```

}

Comment: context issue. tv is a local variable declared in onCreate (and hence accessible only from there). make it an instance field

Answer (score 4):

All of the other answers suggested so far will work. However, I would add in a couple of other notes:

1. if you are only accessing the TextView `tv` inside this onCreate and the DownloadPage acitivity, you can limit access to `tv` by giving it directly to the DownloadPage's constructor
2. for something as useful as a DownloadPage AsyncTask, i usually remove it from being an inner class of any activity and instead put it in a public class called "Utils" that can be used by many other activities as needed. (modularity in code)
3. if you are going to use an inner class (perfectly legal), it's always good practice to make it `private` and `static` for what you're doing.

Something like this:

```
public class FlashResults extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(tv);
        readWebpage(tv);
    }

    public void readWebpage(View v) {
        DownloadPage task = new DownloadPage(tv);
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://seznam.cz" });
    }

    private static class DownloadPage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private TextView textView;
        public DownloadPage(TextView tv){
            textView = tv;
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

         String responseStr = null;

          try {
              for (String url : urls) {   
              DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
              HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);
              HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
              responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
              } 
          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

          } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

          } catch (IOException e) {

          }
            return responseStr;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
            if (textView != null) {
                textView.setText(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why make the `AsyncTask` `static`?

Comment: @Squonk interesting. on second look, maybe it doesn't need to be static. inner classes that don't explicitly need a reference to the outer class should be kept static. but i see here that the `tv` instance will keep a copy of the activity's reference (just from initializing `tv`). This was more of a suggestion for a good coding practice theory, but might not fully apply to this specific scenario. you're right about that

Comment: isn't it a bad idea to pass a reference of a widget - what if the user rotates the phone whilst the file is downloading ... it would crash.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere probably. it'd be good to add a null check in the onPostExecute?

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to do as the other answers suggest and make `tv` instance level.  Alternatively you can make a `TextView` field within your `AsyncTask` and pass a reference into the constructor:

```
...
public void readWebpage(TextView v) {
    DownloadPage task = new DownloadPage(v);
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://seznam.cz" });
}
...
protected class DownloadPage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        ...
    }
    TextView tv = null;

    public DownloadPage(TextView tv){
        this.tv = tv;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: i also like this approach better.

Comment: @DavidT. : I don't. It may work fine for a single `TextView` but what if the OP expands the UI at some point in the future and needs to access / manipulate several UI elements?

Comment: @dave.c : The code is flawed - you've embedded the declaration of `responseStr`, `tv` and the constructor in the `doInBackground(...)` method.

Comment: @Squonk Ah. good catch, i've edited his answer to fix what you suggested. But question - what does OP stand for?

Comment: i think it stands for "original poster". a better way than this, if he wanted to avoid the instance level reference would be to just use `findViewById(id)` in the AsyncTask. i've never understood why people nest classes and then pass variables around instead of just accessing them

Comment: @dave.c : As toadzky says, OP usually stands for either "original poster" or "original post" on forums - perhaps it's an old term and I'm just showing my age. ;) I do also agree with toadzky with respect to passing references in the case of having the `AsyncTask` as an inner class - it's totally unnecessary as all of the methods of an inner `AsyncTask` (except `doInBackground(...)`) have full access to the UI elements of the `Activity`.

Comment: Ah, i see. thanks, i didn't know what OP stood for >_< But your argument is very valid. i see the downside to our approach.

Comment: Just to clarify, I wasn't suggesting that the approach of passing the reference into the constructor was necessarily better, I was just pointing out that there are other ways of achieving the same objective.  For example if the `AsyncTask` were to be moved into a standalone, rather than a nested class, then the above might be better suited.  Alternatively you could also pass a `Context` into the constructor and call `findViewById` to get the UI elements required, if there are more than one or two.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a variable to be accessible outside of a method, you need to declare it outside a method. This is a basic programming concept called scope.

Change your code to look like this:

```
public class FlashResults extends Activity {
private TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    setContentView(tv);
    readWebpage(tv);                
}
```

and it will be available to anything inside `FlashResults`.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the text view class-level variable.

```
private TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    setContentView(tv);
    readWebpage(tv);                
}
```

The other option would be declaring your AsyncTask anonymous, declaring the TextView as final in the same method body as your declaration of the task.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to make tv a feild to make it accessible from a subclass.

```
    public class FlashResults extends Activity {

      TextView tv;

      @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            tv = new TextView(this);
            setContentView(tv);
            readWebpage(tv);                
      }


      protected class DownloadPage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
              protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

              String responseStr = null;

              try {
                  for (String url : urls) {   
                  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
                  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);
                  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                  responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                  } 
              } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

              } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

              } catch (IOException e) {

              }
              return responseStr;
          }

          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
              tv.setText(result);
          }
      }

      public void readWebpage(View v) {
            DownloadPage task = new DownloadPage();
            task.execute(new String[] { "http://seznam.cz" });
          }
}
```

Comment: does this not cause garbage collection issues?  what if the user is constantly changing the orientation of the device and the instance variables are not freed?